# Matlab digits precision ruins the calculation. How to avoid it?

Tags: image, matlab, precision

I work on an image, and i normalized it by its maximum value (3165 in this case).

After some work, I wanted to do some operations with the original values of the pixels, so I multiplied back with 3165.

The problem is that because of the digits precision, not all the pixels get back their integer value.
For example consider a pixel with value of 30:

```
a=30/3165

a =

    0.0095

>> b=a*3165

b =

   30.0000

>> b-30

ans =

   3.5527e-15
```

The error itself is very small, but i need to use it as an index for other vector, and it's not work, obviously.

Technically, i can use `round` after multiplying. It's a good solution, but ugly, and not feels like the appropriate way and good practice to solve this issue.

Someone has any other (more professional) ideas? Or this is the way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Simply keep the integer value and use that. All floating point numbers across all programming languages have this problem (similar to how 1/3 cannot be exactly represented in our decimal number system)

Comment: If that's an index, then dividing it by `3165` is "ugly" in the first place itself.

Comment: This is another option, but not so simple, because this comes after many crops and operations that were done already on the original image.

Comment: @Divakar The dividing is for many other processes on the image. The index is just some "trick" that i want to do after that. The example in the question is not part of the code, it's just to clarify the problem.

Comment: I think you've got to do one or the other: either keep the original (integer) pixel values alongside the "working" values as you normalise/crop/etc. or use rounding or truncation to get a denormalised value back to an integer, with the possiblity that you may land on the "wrong" integer some of the kind (depending on what operations you're doing).

Comment: another idea might be to normalize to the next power of 2 - say 4096 in your case. The resulting number then can be presented exactly in binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The techniques mentioned below use [**`eps`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/eps.html) and [**`fix`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/fix.html). These might be less "uglier" than `rounding` for your case. Let's look at these step by step with some codes and comments.

```
%%// Original indices
org_indices = [15 30 45 60]

%%// Scaled indices
scaled_indices = org_indices/3165

%%// Retrieved indices that are yet to be converted to exact integers
retrieved_indices = scaled_indices*3165

%%// Verify precision issue
check_ind1 = retrieved_indices(1) - 15
```

**`check_ind1`** outputs **`1.7764e-15`** and is not exactly zero.

We can use eps that according to the official MATLAB documentation says - **If d = eps(X), then d is the positive distance from abs(X) to the next larger in magnitude floating point number of the same precision as X.**

Thus, we can calculate such distances/offsets as follows -

```
eps_val = eps(retrieved_indices)
```

**`eps_val`** could be thought of as window vector that determines within which if an element lies, must correspond to the integer that also lies within it. To make it easy for us, we can use the maximum of these window values for our decision making and to make it very safe, we can increase this width 10 times and let's call it max_window_width -

```
max_window_width = 10*max(eps_val)
```

This is not as ugly as rounding because rounding uses a window length of `1` because of its range `[-0.5 0.5]`, whereas this one uses a window length of `7.1054e-14`.

Finally, we can get the original indices back by adding this maximum width and then truncating the decimal portion using `fix` -

```
retrieved_indices2 = fix(retrieved_indices + max_window_width)
```

One can check back the values for exactness -

check_ind2 = retrieved_indices2(1) - 15

**`check_ind2`** outputs **`0`**.

Comment: It's may be a little bit less "uglier", but not exactly what i looked for... On the other hand, it looks like there are no beauty solutions here...

Comment: Once you divide integers by numbers that result in truncation (in many cases it would. e.g. 3 by 10) you lose your "beauty" right there. After that point onwards, its all recovery.

Comment: You probably right at this point. Got your answer for that, thanks!